# Prove, that predicate is inexpressible in the given signature

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have a predicate $y=x+1$. I want to prove, that this predicate is inexpressible in $(\mathbb{Z}, {=}, f)$, where $f = x\mapsto(x+2)$.

I understand, that I need to come up some automorphism, in which this predicate is wrong. But I don't have succeed.

Comment: The point is that $(\mathbb Z, =, f)$ can only relate values with the same parity. $x$ and $y$ have opposite parities by definition.

Comment: @AlexR, how I can to correct this mistake?

Comment: Wich mistake? You can add $<$ to your signature, for example. Then
$$y=x+1 \Leftrightarrow y<x \wedge x<f(y)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$h(n)=\begin{cases} n, & n\text{ is odd} \\ n+2, & n\text{ is even} \end{cases}$$

Then $h$ is a structure isomorphism from $(\mathbb Z,{=},f)$ to itself.

Suppose now that you have a wff $\varphi(x,y)$ that expresses your predicate. Then, in particular $(\mathbb Z,{=},f)\vDash_{x=2,y=3} \varphi$. But due to the isomorphism we then also have that $(\mathbb Z,{=},f)\vDash_{x=h(2),y=h(3)} \varphi$ -- in other words, $\varphi(4,3)$ is true in $\mathbb Z$. So $\varphi$ doesn't in fact express your predicate, a contradiction.